# How to require tab-indentation with CheckStyle?

Tags: eclipse, tabs, indentation, checkstyle

In CheckStyle there is a module (`File Tab Character`) that checks that there are not tab-characters in the source code. Their rationale is:

> - Developers should not need to configure the tab width of their text editors in order to be able to read source code.
> - From the Apache jakarta coding standards: In a distributed development environment, when the commit messages get sent to a mailing list, they are almost impossible to read if you use tabs.

To ensure there is the correct number of spaces, there is an additional module (`Indentation`).

I prefer using tabs for indentation and want to add this requirement to my CheckStyle-file. My rationale:

> - Developers should have the opportunity to configure the space used for indentation
> - Tabs are a logical and configurable unit for indentation, `n spaces` is just an arbitrary number of spaces.

Unfortunately I could not find a way to do this with CheckStyle.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no ready-made check which does this, but you can configure the [RegexpSinglelineJava](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_regexp.html#RegexpSinglelineJava) check accordingly. The following configuration goes into your *checkstyle.xml* under `TreeWalker`:

```xml
<module name="RegexpSinglelineJava">
    <property name="format" value="^\t* "/>
    <property name="message" value="Indent must use tab characters"/>
    <property name="ignoreComments" value="true"/>
</module>
```

It checks if there are spaces in the indent. Setting `ignoreComments` eliminates the problem that Javadoc comments often have at least one space before the asterisk.

Comment: Btw, if you want to check Javadoc indentation, too, you could use `^\t*(?! \*) ` (mind the space at the end!) as `format` regex and remove the `ignoreComments` property. Matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

We can also configure [RegexpSinglelineJava](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_regexp.html#RegexpSinglelineJava) check with the below regular expression in the format field-

```
<property name="format" value="^[\t]*[" "]+([\t]*|[" "]+)[a-zA-Z0-9]"/>
```

This checks for all whitespaces before the first word